# How to filter out a row from a query if the table contains another row with a certain value

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

We have a question and answer table. Tables and contents are below, answers are kept per user.

```
Answer table:
FKQID       Answ        UserID
1           Y           1
2           Y           2

Question table:
ID      Question
1       Do you agree to x and y?
2       Do you agree to x, y and z?
```

We want to change the Q 1's question but we can't change the existing row's question because we wan't to keep historical data about which users answered the question before it's changed. We have a stored procedure that returns the questions and their answers given by the user:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetUserQuestionAndAnswers
    @UserID int 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp Table
    (
        QID int,
        Question nvarchar(200),
        Answer nvarchar(200)
    )

    INSERT INTO @temp 
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            Select q.ID as QID,
            Ques,
            (
                SELECT Answ FROM Answer
                WHERE Answer.UserID = @UserID
                AND q.ID = FKQID
            ) As Ans
            FROM Question q
        ) qq
        --WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN QID = 1 AND Ans IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END --Can't use this 'cos too slow 

    --If I filter @temp with the where clause above then I can do something like
    --this below but it slows down the above query too much
    --DECLARE @1WasAnsweredBefore
    --SET @1WasAnsweredBefore = CAST(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @temp WHERE QID = 1 AS bit)
    --SELECT * FROM @temp t
    --WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN QID = 2 AND @1WasAnsweredBefore THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

    SELECT * FROM @temp t
    WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN QID = 1 AND t.Answer IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    --AND IF @temp has QID = 1, THEN Exclude QID = 2 ????
END
```

This returns the questions and answers for the user. If the user is answering the questions for the 1st time then answers are NULL, which is fine.

What I need to do is if QID = 1 was not answered by the user before (Ans IS NULL) then show Q 2 to the user, which I filtered out in the last WHERE. What I can't do is if the result set includes Q 1, meaning it was answered by the user before, then filter out Q 2. Commented out lines in the SP is what I tried but if I put the WHERE filter on the SELECT which does the insert, then the query is too slow. Another solution I can think of is run the filter on @temp, do another insert from @temp to a @temp2 and exclude Q 2 if Q 1 exists in @temp but it feels a bit too much, there's probably a solution without using 2 temp tables.

So how can I exclude Q 2 from the result set if result set includes Q 1?

Edit: I included sample data above, that's enough data to explain the issue.

calling

```
exec spGetUserQuestionAndAnswers 2
```

returns

```
QID Question                          Answer
2   Do you agree to x, y and z?       Y
```

which is good. User 2 has not answered Q 1 before so the SP filters out Q1 and returns Q2

calling

```
exec spGetUserQuestionAndAnswers 1
```

returns

```
QID Question                     Answer
1   Do you agree to x and y?     Y 
2   Do you agree to x, y and z?  NULL
```

This is not fine, it shouldn't include Q2 because user has previously answered Q 1.

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what you mean. Please add some sample data and desired results.

Comment: I got your first qury that you need to update the question but you also want to store the old question Am i correct?

Comment: Yes Hardik, the old question needs to stay in the table but can't be asked anymore once the new question is added.

Comment: why don't you just define a new question id for your new Q1 and take away the UI code for the initial Q1 and replace it with the new Q1 (or whatever you want to call it).

Comment: @CodeNewbie, because I still need to access the old Q1 if users have answered it before.

Comment: In the question table how do you know that Q2 replaced Q1?

Comment: @Blam I don't, that's not in the table. Maybe I can add a new column to the question table but I'm still not sure how to implement it using a new column.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it but if you have a solution that doesn't use @temp2, or an easier solution, please let me know.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spGetUserQuestionAndAnswers
    @UserID int 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @temp Table
    (
        QID int,
        Question nvarchar(200),
        Answer nvarchar(200)
    )

    INSERT INTO @temp 
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            Select q.ID as QID,
            Ques,
            (
                SELECT Answ FROM Answer
                WHERE Answer.UserID = @UserID
                AND q.ID = FKQID
            ) As Ans
            FROM Question q
        ) qq

    DECLARE @temp2 Table
    (
        QID int,
        Question nvarchar(200),
        Answer nvarchar(200)
    )

    Declare @Q1Exists bit
    SELECT @Q1Exists = CAST((SELECT Count(*) 
                                FROM @temp 
                                WHERE QID = 1 AND Answer IS NOT NULL) as bit)

    insert into @temp2      
    SELECT * FROM @temp t
    WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN QID = 1 AND t.Answer IS NULL THEN 0 
                    ELSE 1 END

    SELECT * FROM @temp2
    WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN QID = 2 THEN ~@Q1Exists 
    ELSE 1 END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(ID) 
  from question  
  left join answer 
    on answer.FKQID = question.ID 
   and answer.Answ <> null
   and answer.UserID = @UserID
 where answer.FKQID is null
```